# Set Theory Counter Example

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For these two set theory statements the Venn diagrams show that they are false, but when I try to find a counter example, the statements come out true. Not sure what I am doing wrong

1) (A ∪ B) \ C = A ∪ (B \ C)

[Problem 1 Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaBXD.png)

2) (A \ B) ∪ B = A

[Problem 2 Venn Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUwf0.png)

Comment: Neither are we. Could you post the Venn diagrams, perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, consider what happens when $A$ and $C$ have a point in common.

For 2, what if $B$ is not a subset of $A$?

Comment: For 1, I'm doing what you pointed out, however, the counter examples still don't prove it to be false. Here is one of them: A={1,2,3}, B={1,2}, C={2,3}

Comment: That counterexample certainly does prove the statement false: $(A\cup B)\setminus C=\{1\}$ but $A\cup(B\setminus C)=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Yes, I see what I was doing wrong. I was performing the (B\C) part incorrectly